# Simultaneously change background-color of both footnote links on click?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, footnotes

I have footnote links and I want to change the background color of both links when clicked.

```
<p id='text1'>Text1<sup><a href='#footnote1'>[1]</a></sup></p>

<ol>
  <li><sup id='footnote1'><a href='#text1'>[1]</a></sup>Footnote1</li>
</ol>
```

This is what I tried but it obviously only changes the ol list link:

```
ol li sup a:active {background-color:yellow}
```

How can I simultaneously change the background color of both the p and ol links when any of the links are clicked, if possible using only pure CSS?

Comment: Are you just trying to change the background of the `[1]` links, or also the surrounding text (`Text1` and `Footnote1`)?

Comment: I would want only the [1] links to change color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, an `<a>` element is **[transparent](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)**, and as such, **cannot** have a background color. What you're looking for is to target the **`<sup>`** element instead. Unfortunately, there's **no way** to target the `<sup>` element based on the condition of the `<a>` tag with raw CSS, as CSS has **[no parent selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)**.

As such, you only have two options.

Option 1: Restructure your HTML so the `<a>` tag includes the `<sup>` tag, and not the other way around:

```css
a sup {
  background: green;
}

a:visited sup {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<p id='text1'>
  Text1
  <a href='#footnote1'>
    <sup>[1]</sup>
  </a>
</p>

<ol>
  <li>
    <a href='#text1'>
      <sup id='footnote1'>[1]</sup>
    </a>Footnote1
  </li>
</ol>
```

Option 2: Use JavaScript:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName('a')[i].parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "cyan";
}
```

```html
<p id='text1'>
  Text1
  <sup>
    <a href='#footnote1'>[1]</a>
  </sup>
</p>

<ol>
  <li>
    <sup id='footnote1'>
      <a href='#text1'>[1]</a>
    </sup>Footnote1
  </li>
</ol>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I apologize if my question was unclear, but my intent was to have the Wikipedia footnote link behavior like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(assessment)#cite_ref-PISA_22-0 where clicking on [22] adds some background color on the footnote text (under 'References' section) below, and clicking on a different footnote removes the background color and adds that color to that other clicked footnote.

Comment: An interesting example. As it turns out, they're using `:target` on `<sup>`. You might be able to get away with that in your example by using `sup:target, li:target { background-color: cyan; }`. The `<sup>` is the element **launching** the target, and the `<li>` is the element that **is** the target :)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is indeed what I have been looking for.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear this solution appears to have helped you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. You'll be able to do that 15 minutes after asking any question. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things on StackOverflow flowing smoothly :)